# Align animation in center without text-align center

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to smooth out this custom animation. 
[See Working Animation Here.](https://jsfiddle.net/ra0nx1h9/)

The problem I am having is that when the city name revolves up and replaces the old one, the text-align center causes the h2 text to re-align center in one frame. I want to smooth out this transition so it eases into the align center instead of just jumping to it.

I hope that explanation helps. Here is my code.

HTML

```
<div class="coverage">
    <h2>Kellin has service in&nbsp;<span class="flip"></span></h2>
    <ul class="coverage_list">
        <li>Larkspur</li>
        <li>Castle Rock</li>
        <li>Monument</li>
        <li>Palmer Lake</li>
        <li>Colorado Springs</li>
        <li>Pueblo</li>
        <li>Peyton</li>
        <li>Falcon</li>
        <li>Calhan</li>
        <li>Franktown</li>
        <li>Elizabeth</li>
        <li>Elbert</li>
        <li>Glenwood Springs</li>
        <li>Rifle</li>
        <li>Silt</li>
        <li>El Jebel</li>
        <li>Carbondale</li>
        <li>New Castle</li>
        <li>Parachute</li>
        <li>Battlement</li>
    </ul>
</div><!-- end .coverage -->
```

CSS

```
/* Coverage Banner */
.coverage{
    border: 2px solid #333;
    width: 100%;
}
.coverage ul.coverage_list{
    display: none;
}
.coverage h2{
    font-size: 2em;
    font-weight: 700;
    padding: 0px;
    margin:0px;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.coverage h2 .flip{
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}
.coverage h2 .flip .current{
    position: relative;
    left:0;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: left;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}
.coverage h2 .flip .newcity{
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: left;
    white-space: nowrap;
    left: 0;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}
```

JS / Jquery

```
var coverageVars = {
    index : 1,
    count : 0,
    flipTime : 500
}

// .current = Current City, position relative
// .newcity = New City, position absolute;

$(document).ready(function(){

    // Load First City Into H2 Display
    var firstCity = $('ul.coverage_list li:nth-child(1)').html();
    $('.coverage h2 .flip').append('<span class="current">'+firstCity+'!</span>');

    // Get Count
    coverageVars.count = $('ul.coverage_list').children('li').length;

    var flipTimer = setInterval(function(){

        // Increase Counter
        if( coverageVars.index < coverageVars.count ){
            coverageVars.index += 1;
        } else {
            coverageVars.index = 1;
        }

        // Get City Names
        var currentCity = $('.coverage h2 .flip .current').html();
        var newCity = $('ul.coverage_list li:nth-child('+coverageVars.index+')').html();

        // Append newcity span to flip element
        $('.coverage h2 .flip').append('<span class="newcity" style="top:50px;">'+newCity+'!</span>');
        $('.coverage h2 .flip .current').animate({top:'-50px'}, coverageVars.flipTime, function(){
            $(this).remove();
        });
        $('.coverage h2 .flip .newcity').animate({top:0}, coverageVars.flipTime, function(){
            console.log('done!');
            $(this).removeClass('newcity').addClass('current');
        });

    }, 1500);

});
```

I figure i would have to align with margins and then put a css transition on the margins but I can't figure it out. Thanks for the help.

Comment: is [this](https://jsfiddle.net/ra0nx1h9/2/) okay for you ?

Comment: Not what I am looking for. I need it to be responsive. But thanks for trying.

Comment: but,you didn't use any bootstrap classes

Comment: You don't need bootstrap to make a page responsive...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An other idea:

1. Get the width of your `<h2>` (without `.flip`)
2. Get the width of the next `<li>` that will be appended. For this `.coverage_list` can't be set to `display: none`, but you can set the `height: 0` and `overflow` to `hidden`.
3. Animate your `<h2>` to the new width (`<h2>` + `<li>`). Maybe with 1-2px more, due to browser rendering
4. Repeat steps #2 and #3 and always animate the width before appending

Comment: Well that works. I animated margin left with the same type of approach. I just wish there was a simpler way. Heres the final fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/ra0nx1h9/3/ Does that look right?

Comment: At the moment I'm not sure if there's a simpler way to do it. Anyway, looks good!